# C# | Listview.Itemssource.orderby(d)

Tags: c#, listview

What does `d` mean in the following code?

```
listView.ItemsSource = notes
      .OrderBy(d => d.Date)
```

Comment: Check the documentation of `OrderBy` at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-5.0). So in your example, the items stored in notes collection is ordered by `Date` and assigned to `ItemsSource` property of `listView`

Comment: I would suggest reading up on what a [Func](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-5.0)  delegate is within OrderBy or most other Linq statement

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, "d" is a local object within the LINQ statement which has access to model columns as well as (if any) parameters passed to the method.

Answer (score 0):

`d` is an input parameter, in the [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions) `d => d.Date` (which is commonly read: *d goes to d.Date*)

To understand what the expected type is for `d` you would have to know the [function signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-5.0) of `OrderBy` which is an extension method on `IEnumerable`. It takes an instance of `IEnumerable` and sorts the data from the enumerable, according to a key provided on each element in the enumerable sequence, via a *key selector* lambda expression -- in your case the `d => d.Date`.

In your case, based on the fact that you're calling `OrderBy` on `notes`, you can think of `d` as an instance of a *note* whatever object that represents.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd have named `d` as `note` instead

Assuming that `notes` is a list of Note objects, `d` represents a single Note out of the list. This is why I would picked a different name for this variable than `d` - I'd choose a name that implied "one note out of a list of many notes"

OrderBy will take the method you supply and call it on every one of the notes on the list. It captures the return values from each call, then sorts all the Notes by those returned values, so if you were to `foreach` the result of the OrderBy you'd be getting the Note objects in `.Date` order

Now, I said that OrderBy takes the method you supply and calls it. `d=>d.Date` doesn't look much like a method, but it is equivalent to something like:

```
DateTime GetDateFromNote(Note d){
  return d.Date;
}
```

Or as I would have named it:

```
DateTime GetDateFromNote(Note Note){
  return note.Date;
}
```

And if you had this method in your class somewhere, then you really could say:

```
notes.OrderBy(GetDateFromNote);
```

OrderBy would loop over the list, one note at a time, calling GetDateFromNote on each one, then sort by all the dates it got in return

Now, in C# we like to find shorter ways of writing the same thing.. It's pretty long to have to declare a method like GetDateFromNote with a name and return type and parameters and curly brackets and a return keyword when really all we want is one value out of it

You can imagine it could have started out looking like:

```
notes.OrderBy(
  DateTime GetDateFromNote(Note d){ return d.Date; }
);
```

But we don't need the method name, because we don't use it elsewhere, so chuck that away. And we don't need the return type, because we can guess it from the type of what gets returned. We don't need the parameter type either, if we make a rule that "the parameter type will be the same as the type of the things in the list" so ditch that too.. and really if we have another rule that a single line method automatically returns the value that the single line creates then we don't need the `return` word.. or the curly brackets because it's a single line. If it's single parameter we can throw the curly brackets away too, so long as we have something to separate the parameters from the body (the `=>`)

So all in we can boil our GetDateFromNote method down:

```
//from this
DateTime GetDateFromNote(Note d){ return d.Date; }

//to this
d => d.Date
```

And that's what you have in your OrderBy